# Matplotlib: Find a region on a graph by mouse click

Tags: python, matplotlib, coordinates, mouse, intervals

Suppose I have a program that plots sine and cosine functions.
I want to be able to select a subinterval or region that is created by the graphs, such as π/4 < x < 5π/4 or -3π/4 < x < π/4.

So if I have this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(-10, 10), ylim=(-10, 10))
ax.set_aspect("equal")

x = np.array((np.linspace(-10,10,500)))
y = np.sin(x)

plt.plot(x,y)

y2 = np.cos(x)

plt.plot(x,y2)

plt.show()
```

I have been able to print the coordinates of a mouse click, but as for going farther than that, I'm stuck.

```
def onclick(event):
    print('x=%f, y=%f'%(event.xdata, event.ydata))


fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
```

How would I:
1. Store the point of the mouse click
2. Check on what interval the point is

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some built in tools to provide blocking mouse input (see [`plt.ginput`](http://matplotlib.org/1.4.3/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.ginput)).

The other option is to roll your own.  The easiest way to do this is to make a helper class to store the clicked values:

```
class ClickKeeper(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.last_point = None
    def on_click(self, event):
        self.last_point = (event.xdata, event.ydata)

ck = ClickKeeper()
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', ck.onclick)
```

The other option (if you are embedding in a large GUI application is to hook up the GUI's call-back stack.

See [`matplotlib.widgets` (doc)](http://matplotlib.org/1.4.3/api/widgets_api.html) and [(examples)](http://matplotlib.org/examples/widgets/index.html) for some fancy built in tools, the  [image_inspector](https://github.com/blink1073/image_inspector) project (which despite the name as generally useful gui tools), [`mpldatacursor`](https://github.com/joferkington/mpldatacursor), and the book [Interactive Applications in matplotlib](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/interactive-applications-using-matplotlib) (written by one of the core developers).

Comment: Wait if I wanted to make a helper class, how would I retrieve the coordinates `(event.xdata, event.ydata)` globally?